# iOS - How to handle universal links with a # hashtag (fragment identifier)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I am trying to set up my apple-app-site-association file to open links in my app but it is not working because I have a hashtag # character in the URL's.

This is what my URL looks like:
https://example.com/v3/#/example/

How would I format the file?
I would be extremely grateful to anyone who can help!